# How to update Tree to 1.7

Tags: 14.04, command-line, tree

I've installed [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) using the command line

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

but it installed version 1.6 and I need 1.7

Any suggestion how to achieve that appreciate your kind help.

Comment: What does `1.7` have that `1.6` doesn't?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  tree versions [change log](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/changes.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. File Size sorting might come in handy when you are looking to cut down on disk usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've succeeded installing 1.7

If you have installed 1.6 like I did uninstall it

```
sudo apt-get purge tree
```

Then download the package from [Tree page](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/tree.html) extract the archived folder `tree-1.7.0`
and run the following commands within it:

```
make
```

and then

```
sudo make install
```